# Swift: Trying to run c function in my swift application gives me linker error

Tags: c, swift, xcode, linker-errors

I know c can be run in swift applications and i've done it before but for some reason when i try to run it now it give me a linker error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_add", referenced from:
> Cprogramretest.ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () in ViewController.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

that is the error I get. The c code simply adds 2 numbers and returns the sum. I don't remember how I solved this last time but I do remember that I was able to run the code in my application. If anyone can help I'd be grateful.

Comment: Is the C code linked with your app? Source file in your project, and selected in your target? Look at the linker statement.

Comment: Yes. I was able to find the solution. There was an error made with the bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to this site on how to add the C - code
https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-call-c-code-from-swift/

but it appears they made a mistake in the bridging header part
in the tutorial it mentions that the c/c++ header needs to be included in the bridging header like so

> #include "header.h/hpp"

This didn't work and gave me the error but after changing the include to include the source instead of the header it worked like so

> #include "source.c/cpp"